# Expecting 'EOF' error when importing a json file in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to import [the following json file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/restaurants.json#) into MongoDB with Compass but I get an error:

```
Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '�' in C:\Users\antoi\Downloads\restaurants.json 

> 1 | �
| ^
```

Then I tried to test it from another source but it didn't work:

```
Error: Parse error on line 10:
...s Park Bake Shop"} { "_id": {        "$oid"
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

is a quotation mark missing? But when I add a quotation mark it gives me:

```
Error: Parse error on line 10:
...is Park Bake Shop"}, {   "_id": {        "$oi
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoimport/)

```
mongoimport --db myDb --collection restaurants --file restaurants.json
```

> `restaurants.json` is not a valid JSON, not wrapped in array nor it has commas at the end.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/